# limitations for cloned profile of Standard Platform User

Tags: profile

I created a profile by cloning Standard Platform User under user license of Salesforce Platform(Let say cloned profile name is Test). i assigned three user for test profile. Now i am trying to assign  a new user to Test, but user license Salesforce Platform and profile Test is not coming in drop down list.

Can we not able to assign more than users to a profile?. If it is possible, how can i assign user to the Test profile

Can anybody help me in this query please?

Thanks in advance

KS Kumaar

Comment: Can you assign any users with the Salesforce Platform licence to another profile? If not it will simply be that you have run out of Salesforce Platform licences.

Comment: No. I didn't assign.

Comment: First thing to do is check Setup>Administer>Company Profile>Company Information to see if there are any Salesforce Platform licences left to use. If not then this will be more complex otherwise you would have to deactivate a user on the Platform licence and then be able to add a new one.

Comment: Yeah....I did not check this Dave Humm. Thank you for Help. Now i can able rectify my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is check number of available licences - if there are no licences of the required type available then it will not allow you to allocate them to any profile. This is done on the Setup page by following
Administer>Company Profile>Company Information

This will allow you to see if any licences of the required type are free, if not try disabling a user to allow you to create a new user with the combination of licence and profile that you need.